# Only need the last 7 days in a SQLQuery

Tags: sql, dateadd, getdate

Is there anyone who can help me find the error.
Basically, I get numbers for a whole month even with this added. But only wish the 7 last days of that month.

```
setting name="SQLQuery" serializeAs="String">
            <value>
                SELECT CHAIN.NAME AS Kjedeleder,COC.CustomerNo, COC.DeliveryCustomerName, COL.ArticleNo, COL.Name, COL.Quantity, COL.DiscountI, COL.DiscountII, COL.DiscountIII, COL.NetPrice, COL.Amount,COL.InvoiceNo, COL.OrderDate, COL.Volume, COC.NameContactNoInvoice ,COC.Invoicedate, COL.EANNo, COL.AltArtNo, COL.IntermediateGroupNo FROM #OWNER.CustomerOrderLineCopy COL
                INNER JOIN #OWNER.CustomerOrderCopy COC ON COL.OrderCopyNo = COC.OrderCopyNo
                INNER JOIN #OWNER.Customer CUS ON COC.CustomerNo = CUS.CustomerNo
                LEFT OUTER JOIN #OWNER.Customer CHAIN ON CUS.ChainNo = CHAIN.CustomerNo
                WHERE COC.InvoiceDate &ge;DATEADD( DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 7, 0)
                AND COC.InvoiceDate &lt;GETDATE() 
                AND COL.Quantity &lt;&gt;0
                AND COL.SupplierNo IN (80012)
            </value>
        </setting>
```

Best regards
Frank

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would help.  (3) Explain what "7 last days of that month" means.  It seems to have nothing to do with your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is only returning the results from 7 days ago.

The where clause should look like:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, COC.InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) < 7
```